# "Separate fields" or "Discrete fields"?

Tags: word-choice

I want to express the fact that a form needs to use two fields, one date field and one time field, to allow the user to enter a date and a time for a task. Should I say "Use separate fields" or "Use discrete fields"?

Comment: Use the everyday ***separate*** (this usage of *discrete* is relatively technical and formal, and doesn't really suit your context anyway, because it has slightly different nuances).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: please create an answer so I can mark it at such. Thank you for your help.

Comment: With many such pairs of similar words you can get useful info by googling **word1 vs word2**, but when I try that with [**discrete vs separate**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=discrete+vs+separate&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&oq=discrete+vs+separate&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59.1054645460j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) all I get is stuff telling me about the difference between ***discrete*** and ***discreet***. But I don't fully buy @BigJ Pdog's point about discrete fields being more likely in "preset option" drop-down lists - I think it's more about being "non-continuous, non-overlapping".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **separate**. Discrete does not mean the same thing in this case. In fact, depending on how the form is to be used, it might mean something different. I would interpret a "discrete field" on a form as a field that only takes one of a number of options (such as selecting from a drop-down list).

Comment: I would agree if you were talking about *values* not *fields*.  A drop-down would have a number of discreet values from which you could select.  However there can be separate, discrete fields, all of which are drop-downs or not.